# groupby functions to get subsequent value

Tags: group-by, pandas

In my data I have stock volumes for order sequence and times, I need to go through each part of the order and find when it ends, by grabbing the next part of the chains time.

I am just starting in python and I would do this by subsetting each stock into its own pool, then adding then do another loop to find the time of the next order for that sequence. Ultimately, in R/Matlab you could go `X$time[1:end-1] <- X$time[2:end,]`

My question: can I use the `df.groupby['sequence'].{for each entry get the time from the subsequent entry}`???

I think `last()` would give me the last value of that entire sequence, I would like the time of that the next sequence starts/ appears

I have a set of type:

```
sequence time
a        1
b        1
a        3
a        5
b        2
```

I would like

```
sequence time  nexttime
a        1       3
b        1       2
a        3       5
a        5       999
b        2       999
```

Answer (score 4):

```
In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
  sequence  time
0        a     1
1        b     1
2        a     3
3        a     5
4        b     2

In [25]: df['nexttime'] = df.groupby('sequence').time.shift(-1).fillna(999)

In [26]: df
Out[26]: 
  sequence  time  nexttime
0        a     1         3
1        b     1         2
2        a     3         5
3        a     5       999
4        b     2       999
```

Comment: Nice and concise, I love it!